# Rails condition where days ago?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@messages = current_user.message_participantions.where(:read => false, :updated_at > 5.days.ago)
```

The updated_at 5 days ago errors. Do I need to use a format like so:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 5.days.ago])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

`@messages = current_user.message_participantions.where("read = ? AND updated_at > ?", false, 5.days.ago)`

Or if for some reason you need to use the hash:

`@messages = current_user.message_participantions.where(:read => false, :updated_at => 5.days.ago..Time.now)`

As the values of the hash argument to the where method can be exact values or ranges: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Answer (score 6):

```
@messages = current_user.message_participantions.where(:read => false).where("updated_at > ?", 5.days.ago)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would:

```
@messages = current_user.message_participantions.where(["read = 0 AND updated_at > ?", 5.days.ago])
```

Comment: you need to use this here `["read = ? AND updated_at > ?", false, 5.days.ago]`